# Selenium Opened Thousands of Links on Same Website, Detected by Captcha

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

As the title says, after I instantiated multiple drivers and did

```
driver.get(url)
```

I got detected by captcha after doing this way too many times. How can I clear myself from the captcha detection? Not asking to solve the captcha itself, but instead to make it forget that I did thousands of requests. For example, if I went on another computer and sent driver.get(url) it would work.

[image: Captcha Response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would start by detecting where the issue was originated (why `driver.get(url)` is getting called). But after that, the page is the one blocking you.

If you can access the site via another device while on the same network, you could try and remove identifying information from your browser (like cookies and that), or better on, resetting it completely. With Selenium you even have the option to use an existing profile, which could help with avoiding the captcha.

Also I would suggest just waiting a few hours/days before accessing the same site again, so that it "cools off", but be careful not to push it with lots of requests again, or you will get blocked again, probably hardly.

Comment: This worked thanks! Just to note, I cleared chromes history, reinstalled firefox and geckodriver.exe (I got blocked on Chrome also so just did that in case), but should I add a `time.sleep()` to slow it down along with the limited request number as you said?

Comment: Yes, I don't know exactly what you're doing, but any server will (should, at least) block you if you make hundreds of requests per minute. I try to never go beyond ```time.sleep(0.5) or time.sleep(1)``` to play it safe.